# Can an element in an array reference an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

If I have an array called `standard` and i want the count of that array i would do `standard.Count`

but

if i was to have a `string` array called `doorType` and i add the `string` `standard` to the first position of that array but i wanted to reference `standard.Count` is there a way i can manipulate `doorType[0].Count` so that it gets the number of elements in the `standard` array?

```
public static List<string> doorType = new List<string> 
{
    nameof(standard),
    nameof(original)
};

public static List<string> standard= new List<string>
{
    "1",
    "4",
    "6"
};
```

How can i make the second line equal?

```
string xform = doorType[0]  + standard.Count;

string xform = doorType[0]  + doorType[0].Count;
```

Some extra helpful code

```
        public static void AddDropDown(string cellInsert, string formula)
        {

            var cell = x.Range[cellInsert];
            cell.Validation.Delete();
            cell.Validation.Add(
               Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList,
               Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation,
               Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
               formula,
               Type.Missing);
            cell.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
            cell.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
            cell.Value = "Please Select";



        }//end AddDropDown



string xform =
                "=IF(B2=" + DO.quote + doorType[0] + DO.quote + "," + "E1:E" + standard.Count +
                ",IF(B2=" + DO.quote + doorType[1] + DO.quote + "," + "F1: F" + original.Count +
                "," + "I1: I3" + "))))";
            AddDropDown("B4", xform);
```

To explain more clearly I want to append strings to `xform` via a for loop using previously made arrays.

This is all for linking C# to excel

Comment: There is no way to do that if `doorType` stays as a `List<string>`. `doorType` should be something like a `List<List<string>>`.

Comment: @Sweeper i was starting to think that

Comment: What's the question behind the question here? This request seems really strange without any context. If you explain _why_ you're trying to do this specific thing, you might get more useful feedback with a much better approach for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts there is no question behind the question? It makes sense for once

Comment: Where are the arrays in your sample? I see `List<string>` but no arrays.

Comment: @JuanR ArrayLists act the same as Arrays? What dont you get?

Comment: Well, if I may ask a few things to bring some context in: What is `doorType` supposed to contain in your program? Do you really need it to reference other lists or just their `Count`? If so `doorType` could be a `List<int>`. What does `standard` contain in your program? Why does it have a distinct variable name if it should just be an index in `doorType`? Is `standard` the only list with the same purpose in your program? And what compelled you to attempt to reference it by its variable name in the first place?

Comment: This is programming. There is no "act like". It is, or it isn't.

Comment: @JuanR well it does then?

Comment: `var doorType = new[] { standard, original }` would work -- *after* the declaration of `standard`, that is -- but even then `doorType[0] + doorType[0].Count` would make no sense, since you can't apply `+` to a list and an element. What would you want there -- `List.Add`? `String.Join`? This whole piece of code seems rather confused in its intentions. There are likely better representations for whatever it is you're trying to model.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Im linking c# code to Excel and making drop downs. i am linking them to previous projects that i have made. Basically I want to make this into a for loop `"=IF(B2=" + DO.quote + doorType[0] + DO.quote + "," + "E1:E" + StandardDoor.Count +`

Comment: @Joelad that context is very helpful, thanks. Maybe you can [edit] that into your question somehow? In any case, that should give others the necessary information to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I've given it an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you can't (easily<sup>1</sup>) manipulate an object from its name, that's it, you can't manipulate the object `standard` (and get its count) just because you know the name as a string `"standard"`.

Instead of putting objects *names* in the `doorType` list, put references to the objects in it. `doorType` will not be a list of string but a list of a list of string. Then you may write:

```
public static List<string> standard = new List<string>
{
    "1",
    "4",
    "6"
};

public static List<string> original = new List<string>
{
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
};

public static List<List<string>> doorType = new List<List<string>>
{
    standard,
    original
};
```

And at this point, `doorType[0]` is a reference to `standard` and you can write `doorType[0].Count` to get `standard.Count`.

**Edit:**

If you need more information in the element of `doorType` (like the original *name* of the referenced list), then you must build a class that will store these information.

Let's name it `DoorType`:

```
public class DoorType
{
    public DoorType(List<string> values, string name)
    {
        Values = values;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public List<string> Values { get; }
}

public static List<DoorType> doorTypes = new List<DoorType>
{
    new DoorType(standard, nameof(standard)),
    new DoorType(original, nameof(original))
};
```

And at this point, `doorType[0].Values` is a reference to `standard` and you can write `doorType[0].Values.Count` to get `standard.Count`, `doorType[0].Name` is the string `"standard"`.

And you may write:

```
string xform = "=IF(B2=" + DO.quote + doorTypes[0].Name + DO.quote + "," + "E1:E" + doorTypes[0].Values.Count
```

And from here made a `Linq` call or a `foreach` loop on the `doorTypes` collection.

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact you can using [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection), but it's not a good pattern for your task.

Comment: If I'm using `string.Join(",", doorType.ToArray());` for a normal List how can i manipulate this to be used for the new `List<List<string>>`?

Comment: @Joelad, I edited my answer, but I will not go any further since at this point it's just began to be a "How to do POO when I came from excel - 101" ;-)

Comment: @Joelad, if you only use the `Count` property of `Values`, then replace `List<string> Values` by `int Count` and call `new DoorType(standard.Count, nameof(standard))`

Comment: I got the answer to my query before `var arrayL1 = string.Join(",", doorTypes.Select(p => p.Name));                                    
            AddDropDown("B2", arrayL1);`

Answer (score 2):

Same as Sweeper's comment, or you could create a class DoorType?

```
public class DoorType
{
   public List<string> DoorTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your standard list:

```
List<DoorType> standardList = new List<DoorType>();
```

Then you can add each DoorType to your standardlist.

```
standardList.Add(doorType); // make sure the doorType object and doorType.DoorTypes exists.

// refer to any items
standardList[0].DoorTypes[x]
```

Just a way.